# Is it ok to hardcode dynamic links in a permanent view?

Tags: django, view, django-tagging

Let's say I wanted to showcase 2-3 clickable buttons on my homepage which will be there permanently. These are links to the `css`, `html`, and `javascript` tag listing pages.

Is it fine to just hardcode `href=/tags/css` and `href=/tags/html` right in my django templates/view?

I won't change them for at least a year or so, meaning I don't think I need to add a column to the tags table to distinguish them - is this common or should I try to make it somewhat dynamic? These tags are in a table but so are 1000 other tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remember to document that you did it in some place obvious, like in tagging/views.py, or maybe you have an equivalent of my **When_Peter_Gets_Hit_By_A_Bus.txt**, in which I document all of these types of *optimizations*. No, I really *do* have a file like that for each of my customers.